# how to reset.one function if needed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this login button where i click it will check on database whether the user match the pw, then it will return from php the result either true/false/nothing.

My issue is that when i use .on function and log in, then i logged out, and i log in again it will run twice, login and log out again and it will run thrice, basically a auto increment of one more running times per cycle.

To avoid that i tried .one function, but this is only effective if i am sure to login succesfully, but if i typed a wrong password it will stayed at the same page and i can't click on the login button anymore as i'm using .one function, so i am trying to check if there is anyway if the php return false/nothing i can add a call to reset .one back to 0?

This is my code

```
$("body").on("pageshow", "#p-login",function(){                 
    $(this).one("click","#btn-signUp", function(){
        $.mobile.changePage($("#p-signUp"), "slide", true, true);
    });

    $(this).on("click","#btn-logIn", function(){
        var username = $("#login-username").val(); // store input val into var
        var password = $("#login-password").val();

        $.post("login.php", 
        {
            username:username, // data to pass into php
            password:password,  // data to pass into php                        
        },  // data to pass into php

            function(response)
            {
                if(response.type == "true")
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    globalUsername = response.username;
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#p-home"), "slide", true, true);
                    console.log(globalUsername);

                }

                else if(response.type == "false")
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    //alert("Password enter incorrectly, please try again.");
                }

                else if(response.type == "nothing")
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    //alert("User is not found in database, please try again");
                }
            }, 'json'
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any problem with using **[jQuery.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** ?

Comment: i never tried that yet. how do i apply it? @t.niese

Comment: Just move the whole `$(this).on("click","#btn-logIn", function(){...` code outside of the `$("body").on("pageshow", "#p-login",function(){...` function, that way it will only run once.

Comment: i wanted to format my code nicely that it fit on the right page when i'm calling it.. is it really better to just move it out?